# having problems running my c program that has two structs and enumeration constants

Tags: c

the question says have two structs

first struct should have these members( string called title with length of 15 characters, double called length, genre of type enum genres with one of these genres  as a enumeration constant Blues , HipHop, Jazz, Country, Electronic, Rock, Other).

second struct should have(string called title with length of 20 characters, string called artist with length of 30 characters, member called song of type Song that contains the maximum of 4 songs, and last member a integer var called c that is used as a counter of number of songs.)

struct song must be aliased to Song.
struct album must be aliased to Album.

my program is like this

```
enum genres { Blues = 0, HipHop, Jazz, Country, Electronic, Rock, Other};

struct song {
  char title[15];
  double length;
  enum genres genre;
};

typedef struct song Song;
struct album { 
char title[20];
char artist[30];
Song songs[4];
int noOfSongs;
};
typedef struct album Album;
```

Now from here i am having problems because the question says.
Have:

1. `getAlbum` function, that has Album pointer as a parameter that prompts user for title of album and name of artist.
2. `getSong` function that has Album pointer as a parameter that prompts user for song title and length of song and genre of that song.
3. `printAlbum` function this function display the information prompted by the user.

NOTE that number songs in an album have a maximum of 4.

I have came up with these function prototypes

```
void getAlbum( Album *aPtr);
void getSong( Album *sPtr);
void printAlbum( Album *pPtr);
```

I am having problems with functions and implementing and also i am  not sure about my enum  and struct album if it is correct cause i can't access neither of them.

Comment: First of all, remember to add at least one more character than the required string length to allow for the null-terminating character.

Comment: Shouldn't `genre` be a property of `Album` rather than of `Song`?

Comment: What is the problem u encountered?

Comment: @VoidPointer Users of this site usually do not rely on textspeak. No-one here is paying by the character, you can spell words in full.

Comment: @PhilipDahnen I think it makes more sense to do it by song. You can have songs of various genres in the same album, especially if its a compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler always pads a type to a multiple of 4 bytes (char = 1 byte), your buffers could use that space without any extra cost. And you need it for the terminating `'\0'` character anyways. What about shortening the definitions, btw?

```
typedef enum { Blues, HipHop, Jazz, Country, Electronic, Rock, Other} Genre;

typedef struct {
  char title[16];
  double length;
  Genre genre;
}
Song;

typedef struct { 
  char title[21];
  char artist[31];
  Song songs[4];
  int noOfSongs;
}
Album;
```

You may of course write `typedef struct album { ... } Album;` if you need the name `struct album` too, but I don't see any reason for this in your case. Here are the functions:

```
void getAlbum(Album *aPtr) {
  printf("Album: ");
  scanf("%20s", aPtr->title);
  printf("Artist: ");
  scanf("%30s", aPtr->artist);
  int no = -1;
  while(no < 0 || no > 4) {
    printf("Tracks: ");
    scanf("%d", no);
  }
  aPtr->noOfSongs = no;
  for(int i = 0; i < no; ++i) getSong(&aPtr->songs + i);
}

void getSong(Song *sPtr) {
  printf("Song: ");
  scanf("%15s", sPtr->title);
  double len = -1;
  while(len < 0 || len > 100) {
    printf("Length: ");
    scanf("%f", len);
  }
  char genre[16];
  int genreNo = -1;
  while(genreNo == -1) {
    printf("Genre: ");
    scanf("%15s", genre);
    if(strcmp(genre, "Blues") == 0) genreNo = 0;
    else if(strcmp(genre, "Hip Hop") == 0) genreNo = 1;
    ...
    else genreNo = 6;
  }
  sPtr->genre = (Genre)genreNo;
}

void printAlbum(Album *aPtr) {
  printf("Album: %s\nArtist: %s\n", aPtr->title, aPtr->artist);
  for(int i = 0; i < aPtr->noOfSongs; ++i) printSong(&aPtr->songs + i);
}

void printSong(Song *sPtr) {
  printf("\tSong: %s\n\tLength: %.2f\n\tGenre: ", sPtr->title, sPtr->length);
  switch(sPtr->genre) {
    case Blues: printf("Blues\n"); break;
    case HipHop: printf("Hip Hop\n"); break;
    ...
    default:  printf("Other\n"); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Philip thanx for helping me, but there is still some errors when i compile the program for line while(no--) getSong(aPtr->songs[4 - no]); i get an incompatible type for argument 1 of getSong

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a function is actually rather simple. You already got the protoype, so you'll only have to add brackets to have a basic function:

```
void getAlbum(Album *aPtr) {

}
```

Of course, this won't do anything yet, so let's start with a simple prompt:

```
void getAlbum(Album *aPtr) {
    printf("Enter the album name: ");
}
```

This will now display the text, but it won't ask for the actual text. To do this there are again several different approaches. I'll be using `scanf()` here, although that one should only be used for testing purposes and (possibly) internal tools, because it can be rather tricky and error prone to use (e.g. if garbage is entered).

```
void getAlbum(Album *aPtr) {
    printf("Enter the album name: ");
    scanf("%19s", aPtr->title); // read up to 19 characters as a (s)tring; the 20th will be the terminator ('\0')
}
```

There you go. Just expand this to read all the values required. Same for the `getSong()` function.

Printing everything will then be rather similar, just passing the members as the parameters of a `printf()` rather than `scanf()`.